# The pdo_mysql extension is not detected on Wordpress Docker container

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, pdo

I have installed several Wordpress websites by using Docker, specifically this [Docker Wordpress Let's Encrypt](https://github.com/evertramos/docker-wordpress-letsencrypt) repo by Evert Ramos.

While it makes it easy and fast to deploy as many Wordpress installations as you want, there're still some issues and lacks, such as the `sendmail()` function (then you have to install [an SMTP plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-smtp/) to work around the email sending).

The main issue I have found is that, after having installed this [WPvivid plugin](https://wpvivid.com/) for backing up Wordpress, I get the following error message:

> The pdo_mysql extension is not detected. Please install the extension
>   first.

I have googled how to install the `pdo_mysql` extension for a Wordpress container or inside the Nginx container. However, I only have found answers about how to install it but for a PHP container.

The [Evert Ramos](https://github.com/evertramos)' repos do not use any PHP container, so I haven't found out how or where to install that `pdo_mysql` extension.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file of one of the Wordpress sites:

```
    services:
        db_projects:
          container_name: ${CONTAINER_DB_NAME}
          image: mariadb:10.4
          restart: unless-stopped
          volumes:
            - ${DB_PATH}:/var/lib/mysql
          environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
            MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}

        wp_projects:
          depends_on:
            - db_projects
          container_name: ${CONTAINER_WP_NAME}
          image: wordpress:latest
          restart: unless-stopped
          volumes:
            - ${WP_CORE}:/var/www/html
            - ${WP_CONTENT}:/var/www/html/wp-content
            - ./conf.d/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini
          environment:
            WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: ${CONTAINER_DB_NAME}:3306
            WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
            WORDPRESS_DB_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
            WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
            WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX: ${WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX}
            VIRTUAL_HOST: ${DOMAINS}
            LETSENCRYPT_HOST: ${DOMAINS}
            LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL: ${LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL}
          logging:
            options:
          max-size: ${LOGGING_OPTIONS_MAX_SIZE:-200k}
    pma_projects:
      image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
      restart: unless-stopped
      container_name: pma_projects
      links:
        - db_projects
      ports:
        - ${PMA_PORT}:80
      environment:
        #MYSQL_USERNAME: root
        #MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
        PMA_HOST: db_projects
        PMA_PORT: 3306
        #PMA_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
        #PMA_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
        PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
      depends_on:
        - wp_projects
        - db_projects

#   wpcli:
#     image: tatemz/wp-cli
#     volumes:
#       - ${WP_CORE}:/var/www/html
#       - ${WP_CONTENT}:/var/www/html/wp-content
#     depends_on:
#       - db
#     entrypoint: wp

networks:
    default:
       external:
         name: ${NETWORK}
```

Any ideas on how to install that extension or somebody who can shed some light to solve this?

(my useful links on my way to solve it: https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/wordpress/ & https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/blob/c9f1ca12b6fa8181dee161dfc5ce1692eeaef1d1/php7.2/apache/Dockerfile
| https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/blob/c9f1ca12b6fa8181dee161dfc5ce1692eeaef1d1/php7.3/fpm/Dockerfile)

Following Anh Tuan's answer, my dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM php:7.3-fpm

# install the PHP extensions we need (https://make.wordpress.org/hosting/handbook/handbook/server-environment/#php-extensions)
RUN set -ex; \
    \
    savedAptMark="$(apt-mark showmanual)"; \
    \
    apt-get update; \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        libjpeg-dev \
        libmagickwand-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        libzip-dev \
    ; \
    \
    docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-png-dir=/usr --with-jpeg-dir=/usr; \
    docker-php-ext-install -j "$(nproc)" \
        bcmath \
        exif \
        gd \
        mysqli \
        opcache \
        zip \
                pdo_mysql \
    ; \
    pecl install imagick-3.4.4; \
    docker-php-ext-enable imagick; \
    \
# reset apt-mark's "manual" list so that "purge --auto-remove" will remove all build dependencies
    apt-mark auto '.*' > /dev/null; \
    apt-mark manual $savedAptMark; \
    ldd "$(php -r 'echo ini_get("extension_dir");')"/*.so \
        | awk '/=>/ { print $3 }' \
        | sort -u \
        | xargs -r dpkg-query -S \
        | cut -d: -f1 \
        | sort -u \
        | xargs -rt apt-mark manual; \
    \
    apt-get purge -y --auto-remove -o APT::AutoRemove::RecommendsImportant=false; \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# set recommended PHP.ini settings
# see https://secure.php.net/manual/en/opcache.installation.php
RUN { \
        echo 'opcache.memory_consumption=128'; \
        echo 'opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8'; \
        echo 'opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000'; \
        echo 'opcache.revalidate_freq=2'; \
        echo 'opcache.fast_shutdown=1'; \
    } > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/opcache-recommended.ini
# https://wordpress.org/support/article/editing-wp-config-php/#configure-error-logging
RUN { \
# https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php
# https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/issues/420#issuecomment-517839670
        echo 'error_reporting = E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_CORE_ERROR | E_CORE_WARNING | E_COMPILE_ERROR | E_COMPILE_WARNING | E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR'; \
        echo 'display_errors = Off'; \
        echo 'display_startup_errors = Off'; \
        echo 'log_errors = On'; \
        echo 'error_log = /dev/stderr'; \
        echo 'log_errors_max_len = 1024'; \
        echo 'ignore_repeated_errors = On'; \
        echo 'ignore_repeated_source = Off'; \
        echo 'html_errors = Off'; \
    } > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/error-logging.ini

VOLUME /var/www/html

ENV WORDPRESS_VERSION 5.2.2
ENV WORDPRESS_SHA1 3605bcbe9ea48d714efa59b0eb2d251657e7d5b0

RUN set -ex; \
    curl -o wordpress.tar.gz -fSL "https://wordpress.org/wordpress-${WORDPRESS_VERSION}.tar.gz"; \
    echo "$WORDPRESS_SHA1 *wordpress.tar.gz" | sha1sum -c -; \
# upstream tarballs include ./wordpress/ so this gives us /usr/src/wordpress
    tar -xzf wordpress.tar.gz -C /usr/src/; \
    rm wordpress.tar.gz; \
    chown -R www-data:www-data /usr/src/wordpress

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/

ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

And I only modified the `docker-compose.yml` file for creating the Wordpress image with the `mysql_pdo` extension:

```
version: '3'

services:
    db_projects:
      container_name: ${CONTAINER_DB_NAME}
      image: mariadb:10.4
      restart: unless-stopped
      volumes:
        - ${DB_PATH}:/var/lib/mysql
      environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
        MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
        MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}

    wp_projects:
      depends_on:
        - db_projects
      container_name: ${CONTAINER_WP_NAME}
      #image: wordpress:latest
      build: ./wordpress
        #context: .
        #dockerfile: Custom-Wp-Dockerfile
      restart: unless-stopped
      volumes:
        - ${WP_CORE}:/var/www/html
        - ${WP_CONTENT}:/var/www/html/wp-content
        - ./conf.d/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini
      environment:
        WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: ${CONTAINER_DB_NAME}:3306
        WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
        WORDPRESS_DB_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
        WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
        WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX: ${WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX}
        VIRTUAL_HOST: ${DOMAINS}
        LETSENCRYPT_HOST: ${DOMAINS}
        LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL: ${LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL}
      logging:
        options:
          max-size: ${LOGGING_OPTIONS_MAX_SIZE:-200k}
    pma_projects:
      image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
      restart: unless-stopped
      container_name: pma_projects
      links:
        - db_projects
      ports:
        - ${PMA_PORT}:80
      environment:
        #MYSQL_USERNAME: root
        #MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
        PMA_HOST: db_projects
        PMA_PORT: 3306
        #PMA_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
        #PMA_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
        PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
      depends_on:
        - wp_projects
        - db_projects

#   wpcli:
#     image: tatemz/wp-cli
#     volumes:
#       - ${WP_CORE}:/var/www/html
#       - ${WP_CONTENT}:/var/www/html/wp-content
#     depends_on:
#       - db
#     entrypoint: wp

networks:
    default:
       external:
         name: ${NETWORK}
```

After executing `docker-compose up -d` I get the following error:

> [pathros@projects wp]$ sudo docker-compose up -d Building
>   wp_projects Step 1/12 : FROM php:7.3-apache
>   7.3-apache: Pulling from library/php 1ab2bdfe9778: Pulling fs layer 1448c64389e0: Pulling fs layer 4b8a4e62b444: Pulling fs layer
>   9eb9d1e8e241: Waiting d20b2d19292c: Waiting 023060ea5930: Waiting
>   a7fa99bc84ac: Waiting 084397ea0b0b: Waiting 27f2e3242e8a: Waiting
>   c53d955b925a: Waiting 55a8a68dea39: Waiting b78786d44570: Waiting
>   69dd7e866b60: Waiting 2907cf87b0bb: Waiting ERROR: Service
>   'wp_projects' failed to build: error pulling image configuration: Get
>   https://production.cloudflare.docker.com/registry-v2/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/aa/aa4bdc74350b45a805ad9bdd39ec2cc38cd604a432e447497c3103ad0a8115d8/data?verify=1568225825-5P%2BOlgyxV6p%2FjAXyu%2BTLKCEU5RM%3D:
>   EOF

Comment: Which PHP version is this?

Comment: PHP 7.2.16 on Apache/2.4.X debian

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `wordpress` image used in this stack is [default image of Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/) and they have very detail documentation of how to install new PHP extension.

First we have to edit some changes on your `docker-compose.yml` file to make new `wordpress` custom build:

```
wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     container_name: ${CONTAINER_WP_NAME}
     # image: wordpress:latest
     build: ./wordpress
```

Second, create a new file called Dockerfile and docker-entrypoint.sh of WordPress default image [here](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/tree/master/php7.3/apache), place it inside `wordpress` directory. Amend some magic code to `wordpress/Dockerfile` file:

```
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
```

Now you have your custom Docker stack with PDO_MYSQL extension and able to run your backup process.

Your stack's config after edit: https://github.com/tdtgit/stackoverflow57447284

Feel free to comment if you need help.

Comment: Thank you. Where do I run that code `RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo php_pdo`. Do you mean, after having launched the `docker-compose up -d` command? By the way, I've added my `docker-compose.yml` file

Comment: After running `docker-compose up -d` I get the following error: `ERROR: Service 'wp_projects' failed to build: error pulling image configuration: Get https://production.cloudflare.docker.com/registry-v2/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/88/888cc7ac71275f9bb3ae71ae50820e9a4b2f49454d9bf8ac4107f263ba281a07/data?verify=1565576313-DueHelIuq1dWw9VRhRz8qjP6Buk%3D: EOF`

Comment: Really sorry for not tested first. I building my config and testing, will share result soon.

Comment: @Pathros Please help to check again :)

Comment: Now I get the following error after executing `$sudo docker-compose up -d`: `Starting ct_wp_projects ... error

ERROR: for ct_wp_projects  Cannot start service wp_projects: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"docker-entrypoint.sh\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown`. Then where and how to specify the Path of that `docker-entrypont.sh` file? I have tried pasting the whole path '/path/to/docker-entrypont.sh' but it does not work. I already added execute permissions to `docker-entrypoint`

Comment: Thanks, I have created [my own Wordpress image](https://cloud.docker.com/u/pathros/repository/docker/pathros/wordpress-sendmail-pdo).